# UBO padding of uint64_t typed array

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following situation. UBO structure that holds 4 uint64_t in an array.

```
  struct MaterialData{
     uint64_t  comps[4];
  };
  layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform MaterialBlock {
      MaterialData data[50];
  }material;
```

The problem is,only index = 0 gives me correct data.But if I change to GLSL built-in type vector of uint64_t, it all works ok:

```
  struct MaterialData{
     u64vec4  textures;
  };
```

It surely has something to do with padding rules for std140.And here is what [OpenGL 4.5 specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf#page=159) says:

> If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment
>   and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array
>   element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), and rounded up to the
>   base alignment of a vec4. The array may have padding at the end; the
>   base offset of the member following the array is rounded up to the
>   next multiple of the base alignment.

So I understand from this part

> the base alignment and array stride are set to match the base
>   alignment of a single array element

that each array's member alignment is the size of the member,which is 8 bytes.Though this is not exactly clear.And in reality it doesn't work.I can get along with u64vec4 but I want to know how to pad an array of uint64_t?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the key phrase:

> and rounded up to the base alignment of a vec4

That means the stride for an array of 64-bit integers is the same as the alignment of a vec4: 16. So a 64-bit integer in an array has 8 bytes of useful data, followed by 8 bytes of padding, followed by the next element.

So in C++, the equivalent array would have to look something like:

```
struct 64_bit_array_element
{
  std::uint64_t value;
  std::uint8_t padding[8];
};

struct UBO
{
  64_bit_array_element comps[4];
};
```

Of course, that's hugely wasteful. A better way to handle this is to use an array of `u64vec2`s.

Or you could just use an SSBO and `std430` layout, for which the offending line in the specification does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

You already are quoting the relevant part of the GL spec, I just add some emphasis here:

> If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment **and array stride** are set to match the base alignment of a single array element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), **and rounded up to the base alignment of a vec4**.

In `std140`, array stride is *always* a multiple of 16 bytes. (This is btw one major difference to the later `std430`, which is allowed for SSBOs). So if you really want the  `uint64_t[4]` type, you need to pad each element with additional 8 bytes, wasting 50% of the storage.

I do see 2 alternatives:

1. just use `u64vec4` as you already do. Since even the `[]` operator is defined for vectors in GLSL, there is no significant difference to `uint64_t[4]`. You just get additional swizzling operators.
2. Since you seem to use modern GL anyway, switch over to an SSBO with `std430` layout.

Comment: Yeah,indeed,waste of space using array... "SSBO access, all things being equal, will likely be slower than UBO access"  https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object   makes me feel like UBO is more optimal for performance.Though I never benchmarked

Comment: @MichaelIV: There are such things as memory/performance tradeoffs. Also, if the array is of a small size, then the cost of accessing it will quickly be eliminated thanks to caching. Lastly, pay attention to words like "all things being equal"; I didn't write those words because I like being wordy.